# Excel unclosed quotes - paste or import from text file

Tags: excel

I am trying to copy and paste (or open a text file), and I am having problems with the quote character (unicode hex 22). When some of the text has an odd number of quotes, Excel wraps it into a single row.

Example - please notes the spaces are tabs.

If I paste this I get a single row, it merges the second row into the first one:

```
a   "
b   c

a   """
b   c
```

If I paste this I get two rows, like it should:

```
a   ""
b   c
```

Is there any way to fix this problem while still using the quote character?

Comment: If your data is in a text file you can get a few more options from excel if you import the data and choose what delineates rows and columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel considers everything from the first double quote to the next double quote as a string and puts that string into a cell, including line breaks. If you increase the height of the formula bar you will see that the values are in the cell.

[image]

Or if you set the cell not to wrap text, it will look like this:

[image]

In order to get the contents into the right cells, you can use the Text import wizard instead of copy and paste and specify the Tab as the delimiter in step 2.

[image]

Also in Step 2 set the text qualifier from the default " to none

[image]

and the result will be

[image]